# iOS application:openWithUrl: - howto get back to invoking app

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, openurl

in my app I registered some "document content UTIs" to be invoked with the "open with..." option from other apps providing images and PDFs. Everything works fine, my app is invoked and gets/handles the images/pdfs sent to my app.

What I haven't figured out so far is what to do when my app finished image/pdf handling. I've seen apps which go back to the app which did the "open with..:", others just remain busy after they've been invoked.

I would like to go back to the app that originally triggered my app, but haven't found how to achieve this. Popping ViewController doesn't seem to work in this case.

Thanks for any hints on this.

Comment: As a common practice you define a special parameter which value your app considers as an app scheme to be celled back, then any app is able to call your app and provide its own launch scheme as the value of this parameter. Some app support it and some don't and some which do don't have any documentation on that. There might be alternative solutions at the recent iOS versions so you might want to clarify which iOS versions you want to target and/or explain why callback parameter doesn't work for you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Just as an example of my intention: I'm using a document scanner app called iScanner. When I'm choosing "iBooks" in iScanner's "open with..." option, iBooks is opened, shows the scanned document and iBooks stays on top. Choosing the "iMessage"app,  I may compose a new message with the scanned document attached to it, after sending the message I'm back in iScanner app. This is the case I'm trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

You cann't trigger app which open document via Your application.